# Saving text of dynamic textboxes and labels on dynamically created linkbutton click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am developing a shopping cart kind of thing. For that, on selecting products they get added to a temporary table, and so on. Then a popup window opens which loads dynamic labels, text-boxes and linkbutton based on the number of rows in the temporary table in the page load event. I want to allow users to change the textbox field which is the quantity of the product, and immediately update in the database using the dynamically created linkbutton.

I tried using Viewstate but I am unable to do it according to my need. Also , I read many other articles and posts on stack-overflow and other blogs too, but could not work out.

Here is my code:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["date"] = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    productListing();
    LabelCost.Text = total.ToString("F");        
}   

public void productListing()
{
    //...................................Product Listing...............................
    con2.Close();
    con2.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adp12 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from db_temporary_cart where(IP_address='" + Request.QueryString["ip"].ToString() + "' AND date='" + Session["date"] + "') ORDER BY counter DESC", con2);
    DataSet ds12 = new DataSet();
    adp12.Fill(ds12, "db_temporary_cart");
    int count12 = ds12.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    if (count12 > 0)
    {
        totalProductRpwsincategory = count12;

        //................storing products id of the category.....................
        arr_product_id = new string[count12];
        arr_product_name = new string[count12];
        arr_product_qty = new int[count12];
        arr_product_price = new double[count12];
        arr_product_subtotal = new double[count12];


        for (int i = 0; i < count12; i++)
        {
            arr_product_id[i] = ds12.Tables[0].Rows[i]["product_id"].ToString();
            arr_product_qty[i] = Convert.ToInt32(ds12.Tables[0].Rows[i]["quantity"]);
        }
        con2.Close();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr_product_id.Length; i++)
        {
            con2.Close();
            con3.Close();
            con3.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adp123 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from db_product_management where(product_id='" + arr_product_id[i].ToString() + "' AND product_stock_availability='" + "In-Stock" + "')", con3);
            DataSet ds123 = new DataSet();
            adp123.Fill(ds123, "db_product_management");
            int count123 = ds123.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            if (count123 > 0)
            {
                arr_product_name[i] = ds123.Tables[0].Rows[0]["product_name"].ToString();
                arr_product_price[i] = Convert.ToDouble(ds123.Tables[0].Rows[0]["product_price"]);
                arr_product_subtotal[i] = Convert.ToDouble((arr_product_price[i])*(arr_product_qty[i]));
                total = total + arr_product_subtotal[i];
                con3.Close();
            }
            con3.Close();
        }


        //................storing products id of the category.....................


        Table table = new Table();
        var collection = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < totalProductRpwsincategory; i++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            row.CssClass = "dynamicMain";

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDivMain = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            createDivMain.Attributes["class"] = "dynamicMain";


            ImageButton imgLink = new ImageButton();
            imgLink.Attributes.Add("width", "150px");
            imgLink.Attributes.Add("height", "104px");
            imgLink.Attributes["class"] = "dynamicIMG";
            imgLink.CommandArgument = arr_product_id[i];
            imgLink.CommandName = arr_product_name[i];
            imgLink.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.OnDynamicLinkButtonClick);


            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv1 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            createDiv1.Attributes["class"] = "sub-category-productsDisplayBlockText1_Dynamic";

            Label linkProduct = new Label();
            linkProduct.Text = arr_product_name[i];

            LinkButton linkSaveQty = new LinkButton();
            linkSaveQty.Text = arr_product_name[i];
            linkSaveQty.Font.Underline = false;
            linkSaveQty.ID = i.ToString();
            linkSaveQty.Text = "Save";
            linkSaveQty.CommandArgument = arr_product_id[i];
            linkSaveQty.Attributes["class"] = "dynamicSaveQty";
            linkSaveQty.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.OnDynamicLinkButtonClickSave);
            //linkSaveQty.CausesValidation = false;

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDivTb = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            //tb.ID = arr_product_id[i] + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            tb.ID = arr_product_id[i];
            tb.Text = arr_product_qty[i].ToString();
            tb.Attributes["class"] = "dynamicTB";
            Label linkQty = new Label();
            linkQty.Text = "Quantity";
            linkQty.Attributes["class"] = "dynamicQty";

            collection.Add(tb.ID);


            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv3 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            createDiv3.Attributes["class"] = "sub-category-productsDisplayBlockText1_Dynamic_Price";
            Label linkPrice = new Label();
            linkPrice.Text = arr_product_price[i].ToString();



            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv2 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            createDiv2.Attributes["class"] = "sub-category-productsDisplayBlockText1_Dynamic_SubTotal";
            Label linkSubTotal = new Label();
            linkSubTotal.Text = arr_product_subtotal[i].ToString();


            ImageButton imgLinkDelete = new ImageButton();
            imgLinkDelete.Attributes.Add("width", "25px");
            imgLinkDelete.Attributes.Add("height", "25px");
            imgLinkDelete.CommandArgument = arr_product_id[i];
            imgLinkDelete.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.OnDynamicLinkButtonClickDelete);



            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                imgLink.ImageUrl = "NImageMainProductImage.ashx?PhotoId=" + arr_product_id[i];

                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Controls.Add(imgLink);
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
                cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
            }


            for (int j = 1; j < 2; j++)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Controls.Add(createDiv1);
                createDiv1.Controls.Add(linkProduct);
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
                cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
            }

            for (int j = 2; j < 3; j++)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Controls.Add(linkQty);
                cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
                cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
                cell.Controls.Add(linkSaveQty);
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
                cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
            }

            for (int j = 3; j < 4; j++)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Controls.Add(createDiv3);
                createDiv3.Controls.Add(linkPrice);
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
                cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
            }

            for (int j = 4; j < 5; j++)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Controls.Add(createDiv2);
                createDiv2.Controls.Add(linkSubTotal);
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
                cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
            }

            for (int j = 5; j < 6; j++)
            {
                imgLinkDelete.ImageUrl = "../../images/delete.png";

                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Controls.Add(imgLinkDelete);
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
                cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
            }


            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        TextBoxIdCollection = collection;
        PanelItemsCart.Controls.Add(table);

        con2.Close();
    }
    con2.Close();
    //...................................Product Listing...............................


}
```

This was my code for loading dynamic controls on page load event. Here is the Enumeration string and click event of the dynamically created link button, which is not working.

```
private List<string> TextBoxIdCollection
{
    get
    {
        var collection = ViewState["TextBoxIdCollection"] as List<string>;
        return collection ?? new List<string>();
    }
    set { ViewState["TextBoxIdCollection"] = value; }
}

void OnDynamicLinkButtonClickSave(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton clickedButton = (LinkButton)sender;
    String commandArgument = clickedButton.CommandArgument;
    int value = 0;

    foreach (Control c in PanelItemsCart.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) && c.ID == (commandArgument))
        {
            value = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)c).Text);

            con4.Close();
            con4.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from db_temporary_cart where((IP_address='" + Request.QueryString["ip"].ToString() + "' AND date='" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "') AND (product_id='" + commandArgument + "'))", con4);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds, "db_temporary_cart");
            int cd = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            if (cd > 0)
            {
                int sendQty = value;
                con4.Close();


                con3.Close();
                con3.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE db_temporary_cart SET quantity='" + sendQty + "' where((IP_address='" + Request.QueryString["ip"].ToString() + "' AND date='" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "') AND (product_id='" + commandArgument + "'))", con3);
                cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con3.Close();
            }
            con4.Close();

            PanelItemsCart.Controls.Clear();
            productListing();

        }
    }

}
```

Kindly, help me enter all the textboxes' and labels', which are dynamically created, values in the database on click event of dynamically created linkbuttons.

Comment: I need help on this question. It's urgent. Please help me.